# split iris dataset into batches and train through epochs

Tags: tensorflow, epoch, training-data

I have seen an example of how to split MNIST dataset into batches and train them in several epochs. I want to do the same for IRIS dataset but I don't know how to split IRIS to batches in python (or by tensorflow libraries). I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: More info needs to be supplied if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code, this will divide your dataset into these 4 variables:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(dataset_name['data'],dataset_name['target'],random_state=0)
```

Comment: Try using thia code , this will divide your dataset into these 4 variables